# "Please check the configuration, the workflow was not able to start " error in litmus chaosCenter portal after opening the status of workflow

Tags: workflow, chaos, litmus

"Please check the configuration, the workflow was not able to start " error in litmus chaosCenter portal after opening the status of workflow"

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while setting up LitmusChaos on Openshift local, it will be mostly due to lack of permission to create a Pod that will create chaos scenario.
You can find the reason of failure in "workflow controller" or "subscriber" pod logs, in my case I found it on "workflow controller", failed to start chaos pod because pod is trying to start with user 2000, the solution to overcome is

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated
```

The above command will grant "anyuid" scc to all the authenticated users. **For production environment, refrain using this command**. Best Practice is to add anyuid scc to service account which you created for litmus agent.

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65231547/8496688
[https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/managing-sccs-in-openshift#:~:text=anyuid,inside%20and%20outside%20the%20container](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/managing-sccs-in-openshift#:%7E:text=anyuid,inside%20and%20outside%20the%20container).

Edit: Instead of assigning Priviliged SCC to all authenticated users, Create a new SCC provided by Litmus team ([Openshift SCC Link](https://litmuschaos.github.io/litmus/experiments/concepts/security/openshift-scc/#applying-pod-security-policies-to-litmus-chaos-pods)) and assign it to the Service Account (SA) which you provided at the time of agent creation. e.g

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged system:serviceaccount:myproject:mysvcacct
```

Ensure that you add the prefix "system:serviceaccount:<project_name>" while granting SCC to SA

References:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_scc.html